# Do not disable the "where" field when "Work Remotely" is selected

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs

I find this incredibly frustrating. I want to find all jobs that allows remote work based on a region (like a country, province or even city).  When you click the "Work Remotely" radio button, it disables the "where" field, which means you don't have a choice as to where the jobs may be coming from.

For the most part, they all come from the USA, which is fine, but I don't have a bank account over there or a work visa, which most of these jobs need to employ me.  What I do have a Canadian and Australian work visa and bank accounts.  I want to find jobs in each respective country that allows remote work, which is not currently possible.

I believe that this should be an option.

Comment: I see that this has been added.  Awesome!